# For each computer found, add it to a security group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using the code below to get each computer that doesnt belong to the Internet Explorer 9 group. Can I just add the following to the code below so that they each get assigned?

Add-ADGroupMember "Internet Explorer 9"

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Testing,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties memberOf | ForEach { 

If ($_.memberOf -notcontains 'CN=Internet Explorer 9,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com') {

    $_ | Select Name,memberOf
#---->Add-ADGroupMember "Internet Explorer 9"
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want:

```
Add-ADGroupMember "Internet Explorer 9" $_
```

The Add-ADGroupMember has 2 required parameters, Group and Member(s). While you and I understand that you are working with the context of that user, the Add-ADGroupMember cmdlet doesn't know that unless you tell it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more Powershellesque way:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Testing,DC=domain,DC=com' -Properties memberOf | Where-Object { $_.memberOf -notcontains 'CN=Internet Explorer 9,OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com' } | Add-ADGroupMember "Internet Explorer 9"
```